# Spring boot application started from start.sh (created by maven) as a linux service

Tags: linux, spring-boot, maven, service

How to correctly write a service that will allow spring-boot application to start with the parameters that maven created in start.sh?

```bash
[Unit]
Description=Some service 
After=syslog.target
[Service]
User=userXService
Restart=always
RestartSec=300s
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /opt/test/start.sh SuccessExitStatus=143
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

At this point, my service will follow the `start.sh` file instead of the `.jar` file, which is responsible for the entire service.

`start.sh` contains bash script that implement some configuration for VM, eg. `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`